# ODAC seems to be caching table schema?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odac

I'm using Oracle's ODAC.NET for a .NET 3.5 project against an Oracle 11 Express database, and I'm seeing behavior that I can't explain (and can't seem to work around).

ODAC should be the latest, I just pulled it 3 days ago, but the versions are as follows:

- Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.112.3.0 (release 5)
- oci.dll (instant client) version 11.2.0.1

I have a Table, People, that has 3 columns:

- ID
- FirstName
- LastName

In code I run an ALTER TABLE command, using `OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`, to add a new column named "MIDDLE_NAME" to the table.  That command succeeds.  If I look at the table with Oracle SQL Developer, the columns shows up.  All well and good.

Now if I run use `OracleCommand.ExecuteReader` with a command text of `SELECT * FROM People` right after I do the alter table, I get back data with **only 3 columns**, not 4!

Here is code that reproduces the problem:

```
public void FieldTest()
{
    var sql1 = "CREATE TABLE People (" +
        "ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        "FirstName NVARCHAR2 (200), " +
        "LastName NVARCHAR2 (200) NOT NULL)";

    var sql2 = "ALTER TABLE People " +
        "ADD Middle_Name NUMBER";

    var sql3 = "SELECT * FROM People";

    var sql4 = "SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'PEOPLE'";

    var cnInfo = new OracleConnectionInfo("192.168.10.246", 1521, "XE", "system", "password");
    var connectionString = BuildConnectionString(cnInfo);

    using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var create = new OracleCommand(sql1, connection))
        {
            create.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (var get = new OracleCommand(sql3, connection))
        {
            using (var reader = get.ExecuteReader())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Columns: " + reader.FieldCount);
                // outputs 3, which is right
            }
        }

        using (var alter = new OracleCommand(sql2, connection))
        {
            alter.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (var get = new OracleCommand(sql3, connection))
        {
            using (var reader = get.ExecuteReader())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Columns: " + reader.FieldCount);
                // outputs 3, which is *wrong* <---- Here's the problem
            }
        }

        using (var cols = new OracleCommand(sql4, connection))
        {
            using (var reader = cols.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int count = 0;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    count++;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Col: " + reader.GetString(0));
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("Columns: " + count.ToString());
                // outputs 4, which is right
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried some things to prevent the behavior, and none of them give me back the 4th column:

- I close the connection and re-open it
- I use a new `OracleConnection` for the `SELECT` than for the `ALTER`
- I use the same `OracleConnection` for the `SELECT` and for the `ALTER`
- I use a new `OracleCommand` for the `SELECT` than for the `ALTER`
- I use the same `OracleCommand` for the `SELECT` and for the `ALTER`
- I call `PurgeStatementCache` on the connection between the `ALTER` and `SELECT`
- I call `FlushCache` on the connection between the `ALTER` and `SELECT`
- I explicitly `Close` and `Dispose` the `OracleCommand` and `OracleConnection` (as opposed to the using block) used for the `ALTER` and `SELECT`
- Restarted the calling PC and the PC hosting the Oracle database.

If I look at the column list by doing a `SELECT * FROM all_tab_cols`, the new column is there.

The only thing that seems to work reliably is closing the app and re-starting it (well it's from a unit test, but it's a shutdown and restart of the test host).  Then I get that 4th column.  Sometimes I can use breakpoints and re-execute queries and the 4th column will appear, but nothing that is specifically repeatable with straight execution of code (meaning without setting a break point and moving the execution point back up).

Something in the bowels of ODAC seems to be caching the schema of that table, but I can figure out what, why or how to prevent it.  Anyone have any experience with this, or ideas how I might prevent it?

Comment: Have you tried issuing a "Commit" statement in SQL Developer?  If you don't explicitly issue a commit, updates, inserts, and ddl changes won't persist, they are simply sitting in an open transaction, as SQL Developer wraps them in one by default.  This is the opposite behavior of SQL Server where you have to define a transaction before you commit.

Comment: Just tried it.  Put a break point between the ALTER and SELECT, ran to that break, did a COMMIT in SQL Developer, then ran the SELECT and I still only get back 3 columns.

Comment: @DavidC you shouldn't need to issue a commit after doing an alter table (its implicit), but stranger things have happened I suppose.  And I don't know why this question got a downvote, seems better than many I see in the Oracle tabs. +1

Comment: what version odp.net? (11.2 rel 5 is the latest, which are you on?)

Comment: I updated the question with the versions.  No idea why it got downvoted either, it's a real issue and I've done a crapload of legwork trying to solve it myself before asking.  No overly concerned about it though - I'm pretty sure I can recognize good v. bad questions.

Comment: Does restarting the system fix it?

Comment: No, a restart does not help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer comes years later but if new readers run into problems with caching try setting:

Metadata Pooling = false, Self Tuning = False and Statement Cache Size = 0

...in the connection string. Keep in mind that there are performance implications for doing so.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#GUID-0CFEB161-68EF-4BC2-8943-3BDFFB878602

Answer (score 1):

Maybe post some of your C# code.  The following is a test that behaves as expected, meaning I can see the new column immediately after adding it.  This is using odp 11.2 rel 5 hitting an 11g db, using 4.0 framework:

The test table is:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
  DTE  DATE default sysdate
);
```

Drop and recreate it after each run of the following C# code (a bit dirty but anyway):

```
string connStr = "User Id=xxx;Password=yyy;Data Source=my11gDb;";
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connStr))
{
    string s = "ALTER TABLE T1 ADD (added_col VARCHAR2(10))";
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(s, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string s2 = "select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'T1'";
        //con.FlushCache(); // doesn't seem to matter, works with or without

        using (OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand(s2, con))
        {
            OracleDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

            for (int i = 0; rdr.Read(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Column {0} => {1}",i+1,rdr.GetString(0));
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Column 1 => DTE
Column 2 => ADDED_COL
```

**Edit:**
Ah, ok, I see what you're saying, it looks like statement caching. I played around with changing the cache size to 0 (in conn string, use "Statement Cache Size=0"), and also tried cmd.AddToStatementCache = false, but these did not work.

One thing that does work is to use a slightly different string, like adding a space.  I know its a hack, but this is all I can get to work for me anyway.

Try your example with:

```
var sql3 = "SELECT * FROM People";
var sql5 = "SELECT * FROM People "; // note extra space
```

And use sql3 before adding column, and sql5 after adding a column.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, what you have here will work.  Doing a SELECT * from T1, however, will not give you the new field and that is a problem.  I've added my test code in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the statement itself is something I generate, and I don't really know if it's been done before (I could add some hackery to count it I guess).  This is part of a larger ORM that I have that supports multiple databases and OSes, so I'm trying to avoid too many specific hacks.

Comment: @ctacke yes, less hackery = good :-) I tried messing with caching as detailed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E15167_01/featOraCommand.htm#CIHCAFIG)

Comment: One would think calling PurgeStatementCache would handle this.  Smells like a bug in ODAC, but at least I know I'm not going crazy.